# How to get response and errors from async function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I try to get value from asynchronous function. to achieve this, I developed following sample.

```
import { myfuncAsync } from 'samplemodule';

const result = await myfuncAsync(args)
```

but it couldn't handle errors.

I must improve them as follows.

```
import { myfuncAsync } from 'samplemodule';

// I would like to define newfunc as follows

myfuncAsync(args)
.then((result)=> ~~ )
.catch((err)=> throw Error("error has occured",err))

const result = await myfuncAsync(args)
```

Are there any good ways to achieve this? my goal is to handle errors and while this,I would like to get its return value.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `try { .... } catch (error) { ... }`?

Comment: the only way to get the response after an exception is to handle the exception (try catch), if there is a valid reason for the exception to be thrown you should be doing this anyway, if you need details about the exception then you return them as part of the response

Answer (score 0):

If, as I seem to understand, you want the error as part of the response, `myAsyncFunc` should look something like this:

```js
async function myAsyncFunc(args) {
    try {
        //...your logic here
        return something // <-- what the function currently returns
    } catch (error) {
        return error // <-- you may want "error.message" here.
    }   
}
```

Now, when you use this like you did above, if an exception happened, the return value will be the error itself.

```js
const result = await myfuncAsync(args)
//. If there has been an error, "result" will contain the error.
```

Comment: you should add async to the function. async function myAsyncFunc(args) {